# C++ compiler crashed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:588:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40,
                 from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:54,
                 from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/weiyang/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/flight/src/qnode.cpp:13:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:150:1: error: missing terminating " character
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:588:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40,
                 from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:54,
                 from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/weiyang/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/flight/src/qnode.cpp:13:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:151:9: error: template declaration of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::put’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:151:9: error: ‘char_type’ was not declared in this scope
```

For some reason, the error above happened, and I try to solve by editing this line

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:150:1:

and after I tried to make my package again and these happen.

```
c++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/flight.dir/src/qnode.o] Error 4
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/weiyang/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/flight/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/flight.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/weiyang/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/flight/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/weiyang/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/flight/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Anyone encounter this before? I've tried to google and some people explains this as a compiler crash. The solution is to get a new compiler which I don't really understand how. Please help thanks.

**qnode.cpp**
I believe that should be nothing wrong because I was just editing a small part of the code.

```
/**
 * @file /include/flight/qnode.hpp
 *
 * @brief Communications central!
 *
 * @date February 2011
 **/
/*****************************************************************************
** Ifdefs
*****************************************************************************/

#ifndef flight_QNODE_HPP_
#define flight_QNODE_HPP_

/*****************************************************************************
** Includes
*****************************************************************************/

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <string>
#include <QThread>
#include "../../flightPanel/msg_gen/cpp/include/flightPanel/flightCommand.h"
#include "../../px-ros-pkg/px_comm/msg_gen/cpp/include/px_comm/OpticalFlow.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose2D.h"
#include "flight/flightFeedback.h"
#include "AltitudeControl.hpp"
#include "RollControl.hpp"
#include "PitchControl.hpp"
#include "YawControl.hpp"
#include "Timer.hpp"
#include "Serial.hpp"
#include "state.hpp"
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>

/*****************************************************************************
** Namespaces
*****************************************************************************/

namespace flight {

/*****************************************************************************
** Class
*****************************************************************************/

class QNode : public QThread {
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   QNode( int argc, char** argv );
   virtual ~QNode();
   bool init();
   bool init( const std::string &master_url, const std::string &host_url );
   void run();
   float rcAmplitude;

signals:
   void rosShutdown();

private:
   int init_argc;
   char** init_argv;
   ros::Publisher chatter_publisher;
   ros::Subscriber commandMsg;
   ros::Subscriber opticalFlowMsg;
   ros::Subscriber depthMsg;
   ros::Subscriber geometryMsg;
   flight::flightFeedback feedbackMsg;
 
   void parseCommand( const flightPanel::flightCommand::ConstPtr& msg );
   int parseInt( const flightPanel::flightCommand::ConstPtr& msg, int i );
   float parseFloat( const flightPanel::flightCommand::ConstPtr& msg, int i );
   void parseOpticalFlow( const px_comm::OpticalFlow::ConstPtr& msg );
   void parseDepth( const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg );
   void parseGeometry( const geometry_msgs::Pose2D::ConstPtr& msg);
   float filterUltrasonic( float ultrasonicAltitude );

   // frames per second in the main control loop
   int fps;
   // sampling period
   float T;

   int state;
   // commands to Arduino
   float pitch, roll, yaw, throttle;
   // roll and pitch angles from 9-axis IMU
   float rollAngle, pitchAngle;

   // px4 optical flow variables
   float groundDistance;
   float velocityX, velocityY;

   // PID control objects for altitude, roll, pitch and yaw
   AltitudeControl *altitudeControl;
   RollControl *rollControl;
   PitchControl *pitchControl;
   YawControl *yawControl;

   // latency in seconds
   float latency;
   // desired altitude in metres
   float desiredAltitude;

   Timer *calTimer;
   // serial communications with Arduino
   Serial *serial;

   // ultrasonic altitude sensor
   float ultrasonicAltitude;
   float ultrasonicBuffer[ 5 ];
   int ultrasonicPtr;

   // depth sensor
   float depthAltitude;

   float referenceAltitude, measuredAltitude;
   int takeOffCount;

  //amcl
   float x;
   float y;
   float theta; 
};

}  // namespace flight

#endif /* flight_QNODE_HPP_ */
```

But there is one odd thing happened in ostream.tcc
(/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:150:1: error: missing terminating " character):

```
 template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
"   basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
    put(char_type __c)
    {
```

How come there is the " at the front of the line? I had compared this with my friend and it shows that it should not have a " there. That's the reason why I tried to edit my ostream.tcc file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97441/c++-compiler-crashed/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should never, ever edit the system files, especially for the compiler.  The problem is probably being caused by some line before line 13 in your `qnode.cpp` file, but not actually causing an error until that file is included.  My guess is that you're not closing a quote in one of the files you include before line 13, or not closing a quote on an include directive.

Don't forget to undo your changes to the system file.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2013-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-11-03**:
qnode.cpp is added, I already undo the changes, and I think there should be no problem to my .cpp file.

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-11-03**:
Hmmm.  It seems that the error is being triggered by the inclusion of ros.h, which is odd, since it's the first real line of code.  Can you compile other things that include ros.h?

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-11-03**:
Randomly, I noticed that the code claims to be a header file (.hpp), but the error was generated by a source file (.cpp).  Shouldn't make a difference for your error, though.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-11-04**:
Can't compile everything that include ros.h. I believe that ostream.tcc is the main problem as every file included is pointing backward from qnode > ros,h > time.h > iostream > ostream and eventually go to ostream.tcc line 150:1.

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:150:1: error: missing terminating " character

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-11-04**:
Try reinstalling the compiler, perhaps, to make sure that your files are correct?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-11-04**:
Yes I was thinking that too, can C++ be installed like python?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-11-04**:
Do replacing my package solve this problem? It seems like the system file had been 'infected'.

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-11-05**:
You should use whatever graphical package manager your distribution supports to reinstall g++.  That should replace all of the compiler files to their original state.